# Facebook Graph API fql query for like count vs direct object lookup

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Why is it that these two queries return different like counts?

1) fql?q... query returns 0 likes

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FLine-And-Circle%2F49561759728%27
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "url": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Line-And-Circle/49561759728",
       "normalized_url": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Line-And-Circle/49561759728",
       "share_count": 0,
       "like_count": 0,
       "comment_count": 0,
       "total_count": 0,
       "commentsbox_count": 0,
       "comments_fbid": null,
       "click_count": 0
    }
 ]
}
```

2) Direct object query returns 436 likes

```
https://graph.facebook.com/49561759728
```

returns:

```
{
    "name": "Line & Circle",
    "is_published": true,
    "website": "http://lineandcirclemusic.tumblr.com/",
    "description": "follow \u0040LineAndCircle",
    "about": "Echo Park, Los Angeles via the Midwest, USA. http://lineandcirclemusic.tumblr.com/",
    "genre": "Indie/Alternative",
    "hometown": "Los Angeles, California",
    "current_location": "Los Angeles, California",
    "record_label": "White Iris",
    "press_contact": "lineandcirclemusic\u0040gmail.com",
    "influences": "Richard Neutra, Erik Satie, Lord Byron, Richard Yates, Grace Kelly, Phil Hartman, Bobby Briggs, Denard Robinson, etc.",
    "band_interests": "Ice cream, ice fishing, etc.",
    "category": "Musician/band",
    "id": "49561759728",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Line-Circle/49561759728",
    "likes": 436,
    "cover": {
       "cover_id": "10151094140979729",
       "source": "http://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s720x720/391388_10151094140979729_1992918206_n.jpg",
       "offset_y": 31
    }
}
```

In other instances, like for username "newfoundglory", the fql query returns something close to the like count, but it is still different than the direct query.

Why is it that these two queries return different results?

Answer (score 0):

The first graph call returns 0 likes, as expected, because that table is used to track the likes and comments for external urls, not internal pages on facebook.
To get that data, you should be using the page table and query for fan_count -

```
select page_id, name, page_url, fan_count from page where name = 'Line & Circle'
```

This returns the expected result -

```
"data": [
{
  "page_id": 49561759728, 
  "name": "Line & Circle", 
  "page_url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Line-Circle/49561759728", 
  "fan_count": 436
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

graph.facebook.com/49561759728?fields=likes

{
   "likes": 637,
   "id": "49561759728"
}

i use this link for generate https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=agenciadac%3Ffields%3Dlikes